# Add random annotations to MKMapView

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

I need to add 'xx' amout of random annotations to an MKMapView, within a certain range of the user's current location. But i can't figure out how to do it.

Can some of you help me?

Comment: what exactly you can't do from that?

Comment: figure out how to add random annotations to a MKMapView

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    CGFloat latDelta = rand()*0.125/RAND_MAX - 0.02;
    CGFloat lonDelta = rand()*0.130/RAND_MAX - 0.08;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = {myLocation.coordinate.latitude+latDelta, myLocation.coordinate.longitude+lonDelta};
    DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"Some Pin";
    ann.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pin %i subtitle",i+1];
    ann.coordinate = newCoord;
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    [ann release]; 
}
```

where: 
myLocation is a **CLLocation** instance.
**DisplayMap** is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface DisplayMap : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```